# remote desktop doesn't work

Tags: windows-server-2008, desktop

Our database server work properly and all the sites that work on from it, but when I try to connect to it using Remote Desktop locally it doesn't respond, just the writing "Welcome", the server's OS is Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, this problem comes after we send mass email to our users. what can be the problem?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Not very programming related.

Comment: @Ash Burlaczenko ok, but where i can ask that sort of the question then?

Comment: @abradr: Your question will be automatically migrated to a more appropriate site if there are enough users that agree it should be moved. You don't have to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your configuration and compare with the content in this link.....

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_Windows_Server_2008_Remote_Desktop_Administration